# How to access public AWS S3 objects in R without AWS account

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have trouble accessing the public .txt files and .Rdata files in a public S3 bucket by using [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) package.

I put some files on AWS S3, and all objects allow public access, the bucket where the objects located also allows public access. I'd like to show others to use these files even when they **do not have an AWS account**.
This is what I have tried:

```
library(aws.s3)
# without showing more details of our data
obj <- get_object('s3://bucketname/folder1/folder2/example.txt')
char <- rawToChar(obj)
char
```

I got content of `char`(hid bucket name, request id and host id below):

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><Endpoint>netzoo.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><Bucket>bucketname</Bucket><RequestId>id_string</RequestId><HostId>id_string</HostId></Error>"
```

Appreciate any thoughts on this error message or any suggestion of how to access public S3 objects in R.

Comment: Have you verified that you can access the objects outside R, eg by downloading with your browser?

Comment: @HongOoi,  I tried to use `curl` command to download the object through its URL, it works. Also I tried to download the object in AWS browser, it worked as well.